# Regex search for a word and extract until a character

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

Need help in parsing a string, where it contains values for each attribute. below is my sample string...

```
Type=<Series VR> Model=<1Ac4> ID=<34> conn seq=<2>
```

from the above, I have to generate the attribute values are below.

```
Type=Series VR
Model=1Ac4
ID=34
conn seq=2
```

I am new to using regex. any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: So is this Python or Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will extract key, value from the string:

```
import re

s = 'Type=<Series VR> Model=<1Ac4> ID=<34> conn seq=<2>'

for k, v in re.findall(r'([^=]+)=<([^>]+)>\s*', s):
    print('{}={}'.format(k, v))
```

Prints:

```
Type=Series VR
Model=1Ac4
ID=34
conn seq=2
```

---

EDIT: You can extract key,values to dictionary and then access it via `.get()`:

```
import re

s = 'Type=<Series VR> Model=<1Ac4> ID=<34> conn seq=<2>'

d = dict(re.findall(r'([^=]+)=<([^>]+)>\s*', s))

print(d.get('Model', ''))
print(d.get('NonExistentKey', ''))
```

Prints:

```
1Ac4
```

Comment: thanks for quick solution Andrej. looking for  any way to search for a specific key and extract it own value. like search for Model in the string and return only its value '1Ac4'... like not using loop and extract value based on key and if not present, wanted to make it to null.

Comment: @marc I updated my answer. You can make a dict with the regex and access it via `[]` or `.get()` with default value (if key is not present).

Comment: thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
r'([^=]+)=<([^>]+)>'
```

This works as follows:

1. `([^=]+)` matches a group of any characters aren't `=` and is at least one character long.
2. `=<` matches those characters literally
3. `([^>]+)` matches another group of any characters that aren't `>` and is at least one character long.

To match a **specific** key and 'extract' it's value, try this (example shown is `'Model'`):

```py
r'Model=<([^>]+)>'
```

This now only has one grouping, the `([^>]+)` grouping that matches the value contained within `<>`. This could be generalized for *any* key, like so: `f'{key}=<([^>]+)>'`

Comment: thanks for the explanation Collin. is there any way to search for a specific key and extract it own value. like search for Model in the string and return only its value '1Ac4'

Comment: Sure, rather than using the `([^=]+)` grouping, literally match that string. Such as: `r'Model=<(^>]+)>'` I will put that in my answer.

Comment: thanks for the solution